# iOS, теряются покупки в приложении

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchases

Возникла проблема со встроенными покупками в приложении - рецепт покупки не доходит до сервера.

В приложении имеются consumable покупки и подписки, рецепт покупки проверяется на сервере. Переодически пользователи жалуются что деньги снимаются, но покупку/подписку они не получают. Вводил логирование покупок, выяснил что транзакции таких покупок возвращаются с ошибками SKErrorUnknown или SKErrorPaymentCancelled. Может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой или подскажет в каком направлении стоит искать ошибку. Были ситуации когда пользователи врали, но большинство ошибок подтверждается логами на firebase.

Comment: Какая схема проверки у вас используется? Опишите подробнее.

Comment: @ALiEN Какая схема проверки рецепта на сервере используется не знаю, сервером занимаюсь не я. Для покупок использую RMStore. Схема покупок следующая: 1) Добавляю в RMStore покупку. 2) В блоке success извлекаю рецепт 3) Отправляю рецепт на сервер с пользовательскими данными. По логам выходит что сначала срабатывает блок failure, который "отменяет" покупку, и следом блок success, в котором уже нет пользовательских данных, т.к. уже произошла ошибка.

Comment: К тому же, блок success вызывается не во всех кейсах, есть кейсы просто с ошибкой 0.